# Pending transactions not mined in private network

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, json-rpc, pending-transactions

I have created a node with the following genesis block:

```
{                                                                                                     
  "config":{
       "chainId":9119,
       "homesteadBlock":0,
       "eip155Block":0,
       "eip158Block":0
  },
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
  "timestamp": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "extraData": "0x",
  "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
  "difficulty": "0xfffff",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
  "alloc": {
  }
}
```

I also have and account with no password and start the node with this options:

```
geth --allow-insecure-unlock --datadir=<path> --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --gasprice 0 --maxpeers 32 --networkid 9119 --unlock 0 --password <(echo -n "") --mine --minerthreads 8
```

and send a transaction via json-rpc as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0",  "method":"eth_sendTransaction",  "params": [{"from": "0x73c30a6b46203c20b6a7a0d7a9469b5a7d285451", "data": "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"}],"id":1}' http://localhost:8000
```

the transactions is accepted and goes into the pending transactions but is never mined by my node.

this is the transaction:

```
> eth.pendingTransactions
[{
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    from: "0x73c30a6b46203c20b6a7a0d7a9469b5a7d285451",
    gas: 297018,
    gasPrice: 0,
    hash: "0xf311038d32174802b54d78184c04f19940a284b22a4361141d87d2296131e47c",
    input: "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",
    nonce: 0,
    r: "0xe381eed0d400150a6c88d512d3d58a34724a6393e58da9ca7f1569a1bf9a1ad7",
    s: "0x46f7f14d5188e62304cf0d79829f0c9683ac495c0aef285a278aac4bd6fe9fd4",
    to: null,
    transactionIndex: null,
    v: "0x4762",
    value: 0
}]
```

I have no idea on how to make it work, any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Note: im using --gasprice 0 option so account balance should not be relevant.

Comment: Does the account used have enough funds?

Answer (score 0):

Check the inputs of the transactions. I had the same problem. I was giving wrong inputs to the transaction.